# How do I connect this Hansgrohe kitchen faucet to my water supply?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet, plumbing-fixture

See the end of the supply lines in the photos. These are not threaded, so I guess this done by compression? I've used compression fittings before on 1/2 copper, but I've never seen this before on a supply line hose.

Do I just use one of the crimp rings and nut that typically comes with a 3/8" supply valve (with some pipe dope)?

[image: Hansgrohe faucet]

Comment: What do the instructions call for??

Comment: It's hard to tell without a closeup of the fittings, but I'd imagine that they go into some sort of matching fitting, provided with the faucet, that is screwed/soldered/crimped onto the supply lines. This allows you to make up the connection to the supply line, then drop the hoses through the hole & simply push to connect. Again, that's my _guess_.

Comment: I think your best bet is to contact  Hansgrohe - https://www.hansgrohe-usa.com/contact

Comment: Will reach out to Hansgrohe. I bought this on ebay, there were no instructions. I looked up instructions for the same model and it seemed to have a typical supply hose with a threaded 3/8 female at the end. So thinking maybe this is a European version or something? Serves me right I guess for trying to save money and shop ebay.

Comment: I think some adapter(s) might be missing...

Comment: This might be a Tali's M52 with some kind of "s box" (manufacturer term) that apparently retracts the sprayer hose...let us know what you find out from Hansgrohe!